# IBM Worklight JSONStore Auto-increment field

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, auto-increment, jsonstore

I use Worklight JSONStore and I need a numeric field autoincrement.
I tried this way but it did not work.

```
var COLLECTION_SPESE = {
    Spese : {
        searchFields:
            {id: "INTEGER primary key autoincrement", importo: "string", valuta: "string", metodoPagamento: "string", 
            acconto: "string", data: "string", motivazione: "string", categoria: "string", 
            icona: "string", checked: "boolean"}
    }
};
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to provide code to do the auto-incrementing yourself. For example `WL.JSONStore.get('collection').add({id: getLastId() + 1, ...})`. The `getLastId()` function would return the last id value used in the collection. You would have to write the implementation for the `getLastId` function. The search field type for `id` would be `integer`.

Alternatively, you could depend of the value of `_id` which is generated by JSONStore. It is an auto-incremented integer starting from `1`. The value assigned to `_id` is never re-used, for example, if you remove the document with `_id == 1` and then add a new one, `1` is not used again for the new document.

```
WL.JSONStore.get('collection').add({name: 'carlos})
.then(function () {
  return WL.JSONStore.get('collection').findAll();
})
.then(function (res) {
  //res => [{_id: 1, json: {name: 'carlos'}}]
})
```

FYI - Feature requests [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014907906&ps=25).